# Asus Eee Netbook Distribution

Tags: distribution-choice, distributions, small-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are suitable distros for the Asus EEE PC 701 4G?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26035/what-are-suitable-distros-for-the-asus-eee-pc-701-4g)

In our school we have Asus Eee Netbooks working with Lubuntu 11.10. The problem is that we need a new distro, because the touchpad isnt working and the newer version doesn't include the driver! Do you have suggestions for an appropriate distro?

Comment: Maybe you could provide the model of the touchpad, and some requirements like the kind of software your are willing to use, to avoid just deciding on which distribution is supposedly the best ?

Answer (score 1):

A better question to ask might be how to fix the problem, especially if the touchpad issue is a regression from previous versions.  And the Ubuntu bugtracker is the best place to start.  For example, [Bug 859474](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/859474) suggests some workarounds for touchpad dragging issues, and the commenters there mention that the problem was fixed in 12.04.  [Bug 868400](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/868400) is another touchpad problem that showed up in 11.10; some workarounds are shown and it looks like it was recently fixed in an upgraded `gnome-settings-daemon` package.

The same bugtracker is the place to report problems like this.  Be sure to include all relevant info (the exact problem, your computer's model, etc) for the best chance of finding a solution.